# List runtime-only changes in firewalld

Tags: firewalld

Is there a way to list runtime-only (i.e. no `--permanent`) changes in firewalld? I would like to see a diff in my configuration to make sure no change will get lost in case of a `--reload`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as I can see no tool that offers you that possibility, but you can create it yourself.

I add a runtime acl to port 54/tcp:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-port=54/tcp
```

Then I can save the runtime rules to a file:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all > /tmp/runtime_rules
```

And I save the permanent rules to another file:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all --permanent > /tmp/permanent_rules
```

Finally I use diff to compare both

```
# diff /tmp/runtime_rules /tmp/permanent_rules 
1c1
< FedoraWorkstation (active)
---
> FedoraWorkstation
4c4
<   interfaces: wlp2s0
---
>   interfaces: 
7c7
<   ports: 1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp 54/tcp
---
>   ports: 1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp
```

And there you have the port I added on the runtime rules, not on the permanent one.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: This seems to only list the default zone. For example, if I run `firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.0.2.1/32 --permanent`, that doesn't show up in `firewall-cmd --list-all --permanent` which for me lists the `public` zone my intefrace is in.

Something to be aware of if you use multiple zones

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose a one-liner alternative usable in a bash shell:

```sh
diff -u <(firewall-cmd --list-all --permanent) <(firewall-cmd --list-all)
```

```
--- /dev/fd/63  2022-02-20 14:05:38.106385643 +0000
+++ /dev/fd/62  2022-02-20 14:05:38.110385485 +0000
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
   icmp-block-inversion: no
   interfaces: eno0
   sources: 
-  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
+  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
   ports: 
   protocols: 
   forward: no
```

Lines prefixed with `-` are in the permanent config. Those with `+` are  in the live configuration.